# Start application anyway IIS

Tags: c#, iis, web-applications

I'm tried to automatic start `IIS WebApplication`.

I want to be able to call to `Application_Start` inside my `global.asax` but its happend only after the first request to my web application.
How can i do it when the IIS server is started??

Thanks.

Comment: see Related links, this is already asked question.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement System.Web.Hosting.IProcessHostPreloadClient interface and load your datas in the Preload method.
You then need to configure a serviceAutoStartProviders in IIS.